# How to replace 2 -gang kitchen/living room switch that also feeds hallway light

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

We are replacing a 2-gang light switch with an Iotty smart switch and we encountered a roadblock. We were expecting the wires in the box only to control the kitchen and living room light, but apparently, they also feed a hallway light.
We have neutral and load on the left; live, neutral & traveler in the middle; neutral and load on the right.
The picture of the switch wiring is below.
Where would the traveler wire go?
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: A clear, focused picture of the back of the switch so we can read the connector labeling would be very, _very_ helpful (as well as the make/model of the switch). Also, do you know which cable is which going into the box? There's a blue taped /2 a black(?) taped /2 and the unmarked /3. Which has hot power coming into the box, which goes to the kitchen, which to the hall, and which to the living room. You didn't happen to take pics of the old switches before you disassembled everything did you?

Comment: Not the best picture, I agree. What we have in the box is: neutral + load (left); live + load (?) + neutral (middle); neutral + load (right). I'll update the post to add picture of the back of the switch.

Comment: As noted in a comment on a now deleted non-answer, the green marked wire is _not_ a ground. Because of the confusion green brings, it should _never_ be used for marking wires that aren't a ground!

Comment: What on earth are we looking at here?  What's with all the ganky "making the wires stick slightly together"?  *Seriously, if you would post this on a public forum, maybe  you should not be touching AC electrical, and just hire a pro*.  "I don't own any wire nuts" is an easily fixed problem, Home Depot does curbside and get about 6' of by-the-foot 12/3 cable while you're at it - bare ground wires *as pigtails* dear Joseph, **you need to have more fear of electricity - seriously**.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, even?

Comment: You should _really_ put the _actual_ picture back up. It will really help people help you figure out what's going on. Yes, it's a mess, but these guys are pretty darn good at sorting out disasters if they can _see_ what's going on. Without the pic, the only real advice we can offer is "hire someone". That may well be the answer anyway, but give yourself a chance...